# SRSS Generate report on a user defined Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I want to create a report in SSRS which accepts a SQL Query from the User (may be as a String), then execute it and display the results.
I tried to create a report with the below query

```
SELECT @select
FROM @from
WHERE @ where
```

And planned to show 3 text boxes to the user to get each input. But this is giving me error while creating the report itself.
Any suggestions to do this ?

Comment: perhaps you should be using report-builder http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/ff657833.aspx

Comment: Not really an ideal way to set this up. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: good one @SarekOfVulcan. But I would give read only permissions to other users. I am guessing there is some way to set these permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the dataset to use an expression instead of a hard-coded query but you will need to use an embedded data source rather than a shared data source. When you use an embedded data source, you click the fx button (the expression button) to put in the expression that resolves as a SQL query. You could use the three parameters that you capture from the user in an expression like this:

```
="select " + @select + " from " + @from + " where " + @where
```

The problem with this approach is that Reporting Services resolves the query as a set of fields that then are defined in the report layout. If you could guarantee the same number of fields in each execution of the query, and if you could convert the column names to a generic column name using an alias (column_1, column_2, etc.), then you could create a report layout that would display the results of the query. I doubt very much that whoever is going to put in column names in the Select parameter is going to want to type in (or know to type in) columnA as column_1, columnB as column_2, etc, but I could be wrong. The bigger problem is you have no way of validating that the correct number of columns is used every time. I suppose you could write a custom function in the report and fill in extra columns if needed. So if you built the report to display 5 columns but they only provided 3, you could parse the Select parameter and have "null as column_4, null as column_5" added in, or conversely truncate the number of columns to a set of 5 if they entered in 10. For that matter if you add a custom function, you could accept the column list from the user and then rewrite the string by adding in the generic column names afterwards.

You also have an issue validating user input in each parameter - but again you could write a custom function to deal with this. The bottom line is that it's not trivial and not really the way that SSRRS was intended to be used. But if you put in enough work into it, there's probably a way to make it do what you want.